# Java application with SSO (SAML) and ADFS

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs

I am creating a java application to implement SSO (SAML) using ADFS. I am not sure if SAML can be done using ADFS alone. While installing ADFS, I noticed that it required configurations of relying party and claim providers trusts (which are basically the SP and IP, right?). I am confused as to whether to have SP and IP in the java application, or just leave it to the ADFS to handle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Java application needs a SAML stack and becomes the SP.

Refer: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html) for some ideas if you don't have one.

ADFS (which handles SAML 2.0) can then function as the IDP.

You will also have to configure the claims in ADFS - which correspond to the SAML assertions.

Comment: Thanks @nzpcmad ! I am using a claims aware application on visual studio to implement SSO now. Then I am planning to call the .net application from my java application. I am hoping it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java application will be a Service Provider (SP) that receives identity from an Identity Provider (IdP) server.  In the use case you have outlined, ADFS will be the IdP Server.  within your application you will need to integrate a library (e.g. SAML stack) to process the SAML assertion. SAML requires configuration on both sides of the interface.  There are a few open source options such as [OpenSAML](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home/). Depending on your organization, you may want to look at a vendor provided solution as well for long term support.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I am using a claims aware application on visual studio to implement SSO now. Then I am planning to call the .net application from my java application. I am hoping it will work.